# get value from right resut scala

Tags: scala

Using this code:

```
for {
  id1 <- invDAO.save(inv)
} yield {
  println(s"id1, $id1")
}
```

I get : `id1, Right(7f5c7a58-8caa-4329-8a21-df27ed5d661b)`
How can I access the id value?

Comment: Use `.save(..).right` to have a for-comprehension (`flatMap`) on the right projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to match the result from `save`:

```
for {
  Right(id1) <- invDAO.save(inv)
} yield {
  println(s"id1, $id1")
}
```

which would print `id1, 7f5c7a58-8caa-4329-8a21-df27ed5d661b`

Of course - this would only work for return values which indeed match the pattern, i.e. are instances of `Right`. If a `Left` is returned, you'll get no matches and nothing will be printed.

Comment: Your last statement is false, no MatchError will be thrown. The compiler will add a filter which checks if the return value is a `Right`, if it is a `Left`, then it is skipped and the yield block will not be executed.

Comment: correct! that's what I thought too, then I tested it and got a MatchError, but now I see I tested it wrong. Thanks @Wellingr

Answer (score 3):

`Right` is one of the two subtypes of `Either` (the other one is `Left`).

`Either` is a type similar two `Option` (which has `Some` and `None` as its subtypes). Just like `Option` is used to capture the idea that a method can have an empty result, `Either` is used to return either a result (in a `Right`) or an error value (in a `Left`).

You should match on the return value of `invDAO.save(inv)` to see if it returns a `Right` or a `Left`, and handle the result appropriately. For example:

```
invDAO.save(inv) match {
  case Right(id1) => println(s"id1, $id1")
  case Left(msg)  => println(s"An error occurred: $msg")
}
```

**edit** - if `invDao.save(inv)` actually returns something like a `Seq` of `Either`, then ofcourse you can use `for`:

```
for (result <- invDao.save(inv)) result match {
  case Right(id1) => println(s"id1, $id1")
  case Left(msg)  => println(s"An error occurred: $msg")
}
```

Comment: not sure this is accurate - looks like `save`'s return type is something like `Seq[Either[L, R]]` or `Option[Either[L, R]]`, and not simply `Either[L, R]` - otherwise the original code in the question won't compile.